# How to convert String Array to String in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I need to convert a `String` array into single `String`.

This is my array:

> ["1","2","3","4","5"]

I need to get this:

> "["1","2","3","4","5"]"

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: i saw this question already  your link provide answer without array i want array please have a look

Comment: Inside the enclosing double quotes, double quotes needs to be escaped. So, your `"["1","2","3","4","5"]"` cannot be a valid string in any possible use cases. For what do you want the single string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
let string = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

let newString = "\"[\"" + string.joined(separator: "\",\"") + "\"]\""

print(newString) // Prints "["1","2","3","4","5"]"
```

Edit: The best way is to use [@vadian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52293802/7734643)'s answer. Albeit, this doesn't seem like a valid use case.

Comment: getting the same array ["1","2","3","4","5"]

Comment: @Jhony but as a single string. You want the string to enclose in double quotes as well?

Comment: yes i want with quoted like this "["1","2","3","4","5"]"

Comment: @Jhony check edit. can you explain your use case also? :/

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: You don't need to use join, you can do it in a simple way like: "\"\(string)\""

Comment: @Jhony: Try this also

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary Please don't take offense when i say this. But in the same screenshot run my code and print it below yours to see the difference.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: This is not about offense or diffrence. This is the way

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary Your O/P is not what OP wants sir. I do not know why he wants the O/P he wants, it makes no sense, but this answer gives him what he wants exactly like how he has asked in the question.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: Have you checked my answer as i have added screenshots.  So don,t day that your answer does not answer. BTW Your answer is also a perfect answer. Let leave the topic, Thank you sir

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary i saw your screenshots and i am still telling you that is not the exact answer OP wants. My first comment on yours answer tells you why. If you run my code and print it alongside yours, you could literally see why. But your blatantly refuse to do so and keep on arguing, i do not understand why. :(

Comment: This is an horrible hack you should tell OP to use the proper tools

Comment: `JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrayOfStrings)`

Comment: @LeoDabus a better answer has already been posted, which with little modification will achieve what OP wants, but seems like the person who posted the answer doesn't want to make those changes. And my answer is not wrong, just not the best. Doesn't mean i shouldn't post it as an answer. This is what i know. Next time i encounter this situation, i'll probably think of JSON. I don't see the point of downvotes when it clearly says "The answer is not helpful".

Comment: @Jhony kindly remove the accepted mark and mark vadian's answer accepted. You just need to append quotes on both sides of that answer to get what you need. My answer is **not wrong** but not the way to solve your problem.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I did NOT vote it down. Btw there is no need to append quotes on both sides

Comment: @LeoDabus i’m sorry sir if it seemed like i was saying you downvoted. I was talking in general in the last line. Might look out of context there. No accusations at you intended there. Sorry.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri *You just need to append quotes on both sides*. Actually you don't need. These quotes are the regular literal string quotes

Comment: @vadian it seems like he wants those literals in his string. I do not know why.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri The string printed with `debugDescription` is exactly the expected string in the question (except the necessary virtually added backslashes).

Comment: @vadian i did not know that! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The result is a JSON string so use `JSONEncoder`

```
let array =  ["1","2","3","4","5"]
do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(array)
    let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(string.debugDescription) // "[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\"]"
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: getting ["1","2","3","4","5"] i want this array in quoted  ""

Comment: It **is** in double quotes, believe me. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code for swift 4**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let strArray = self.getString(array: ["1", "2", "3"])
        print(strArray)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func getString(array : [String]) -> String {
        let stringArray = array.map{ String($0) }
        return stringArray.joined(separator: ",")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want from `["1","2","3","4","5"]` to `"["1","2","3","4","5"]"` then check

You can do this in simple way, Please try this

```
 let arr = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
 let str = "\"\(arr)\""
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this introduces an extra space between the elements.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: Print this on console then show me.

Comment: I believe you can do that yourself.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Now check

Comment: _facepalm_ _sigh_

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Array {

    var fancyString: String {
        let formatted = self.description.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        return "\"\(formatted)\""
    }
}

let array = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
print(array.fancyString) //"["1","2","3","4","5"]"
```

Note: this solution will work with `Array`s of any type

```
let ints = [1, 1, 3, 5, 8]
print(ints.fancyString) // "[1,1,3,5,8]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your array into CSV string using this.

```
let productIDArray = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
let productIDString = productIDArray.joined(separator: ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func objectToJSONString(dictionaryOrArray: Any) -> String? {
do {
    
    //Convert to Data
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionaryOrArray, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
    
    //Convert back to string. Usually only do this for debugging
    if let JSONString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        return JSONString
    }
    
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

return nil
}
```

Output will be

[image: Playground test]

## Edit for an exact answer

Declare a string extension for string

```
extension String {
var unescaped: String {
    let entities = ["\0": "\\0",
                    "\t": "\\t",
                    "\n": "\\n",
                    "\r": "\\r",
                    "\"": "\\\"",
                    "\'": "\\'",
                    ]
    
    return entities
        .reduce(self) { (string, entity) in
            string.replacingOccurrences(of: entity.value, with: entity.key)
        }
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\\(?!\\\\)", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        .replacingOccurrences(of: "\\\\", with: "\\")
}
}
```

Modified code will be

```
let array = ["1","2","3","4","5"]

let jsonString = objectToJSONString(dictionaryOrArray: array)

print(jsonString!.debugDescription) // this will print "[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\"]"

let result = jsonString!.debugDescription.unescaped

print(result)
```

So Output

[image]

***Happy Coding :)***

Comment: This is what OP is looking for but he doesn’t know yet

Comment: I am not getting. OP?

Comment: Original poster

Comment: @vadian answer it is also correct for Swift 4 or later

Comment: oh! It depends on OP now.